# SQL recursive CTE query error 'invalid column name - level'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

Trying to write a recursive CTE query, keep getting the following error: `level, invalid column name`

This is the query, where am I going wrong?

```
WITH OwnerHierarchy AS (
   SELECT PairID, 
          ChildID, 
          ParentID, 
          0 AS level
     FROM BusinessHierarchy
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.PairID, 
          e.ChildID, 
          e.ParentID, 
          level + 1 AS level
     FROM BusinessHierarchy AS e 
     JOIN BusinessHierarchy AS eh ON e.ParentID = eh.ParentID)
 SELECT PairID, 
        ChildID, 
        ParentID, 
        level
    FROM OwnerHierarchy AS OwnerHierarchy_1
 ORDER BY level, ChildID, ParentID
```

This is ms sql server 2005.

Comment: I did vote, i'm sure of it :)

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry I didn't respond earlier, had doctor stuff to deal with, but glad to see you're able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's three issues with what you posted:

```
WITH OwnerHierarchy AS (
   SELECT a.pairid, 
          a.childid, 
          a.parentid, 
          0 AS level
     FROM BusinessHierarchy a
    WHERE a.parentid IS NULL -- Point #1, see below
   UNION ALL
   SELECT b.PairID, 
          b.ChildID, 
          b.ParentID, 
          oh.level + 1 AS level
     FROM BusinessHierarchy AS b
     JOIN OwnerHierarchy oh ON oh.childid = b.parentid) -- Points #2 & 3, see below
 SELECT x.PairID, 
        x.ChildID, 
        x.ParentID, 
        x.level
    FROM OwnerHierarchy x
 ORDER BY x.level, x.ChildID, x.ParentID
```

Points:

1. The top half of the UNION is missing what determines what the root nodes/records/rows are.  I've assumed, hopefully correctly...
2. You were joining `BusinessHierarchy` to itself, when the reference should be the CTE name
3. The relationship between the CTE and original table needs to be correct, and in the correct direction

Props for using table aliases, but they weren't consistently used, and they should be as brief as possible.  You don't need to use the `AS` when defining them, just a matter of style on that part.

### Conclusion

---

I'm thinking the table aliases will deal with the `level` column not being found issue, but not 100%.

Comment: I am missing something as I am not getting any results.  If I run the first part of the query I get nothing unless I remove the:    
    
    WHERE a.parentid IS NULL

Line, but when I run the entire query with this line removed then my IDE crashes.  Truthfully I'm not really understanding all of the CTE aspects but I guess it is getting better the more I look at it.  Thanks

Comment: OK, I found out what the error was, which was awesome.  This helped enormously, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need `OwnerHierarchy` somewhere in the second half of the CTE to be recursive. Instead, you have `BusinessHierarchy` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing at the exact requirements, but something like this.

```
WITH OwnerHierarchy(PairID, ChildID, ParentID, level)
AS 
(
     SELECT PairID, ChildID, ParentID, 0 AS level
     FROM BusinessHierarchy
     WHERE ParentID IS NULL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT e.PairID, e.ChildID, e.ParentID, level + 1 AS level
     FROM BusinessHierarchy AS e 
     INNER JOIN OwnerHierarchy AS eh 
     ON e.ParentID = eh. ChildID
     )
 SELECT     PairID, ChildID, ParentID, level
 FROM         OwnerHierarchy AS OwnerHierarchy_1
 ORDER BY level, ChildID, ParentID
```

Comment: I tried this several different ways and I am either getting no results (there are several test cases in the database) or visual studio crashes!

Comment: OK, scratch that, we have two different versions of MS SQL and the test environment doesn't support common tables of course!  However, it is returning no datasets which is weird as I know there is definitely a couple of test cases that should be returned at least!